Is washout a twist up at the root or a twist down at the tip of the wing?
Does washout/in take place at the root of the wing or the tip? And is the twist distributed evenly along the wing, or is it only twisted for a portion and level for the rest, specifically in commercial airliners?

"Does washout/in take place at the root of the wing or the tip?"  Have you heard the term "frame of reference"?

Washout is chordline twisting nose down toward the tip. When it starts is not important. There is washout if the angle of incidence of the tip is lower than the root.
Wash-in is the opposite.
Sometimes the effect of washout is achieved by changing the airfoil contour toward the tip without actually twisting the wing, with the change to an airfoil with a higher stalling AOA near the tip. Or you might achieve this simply by adding a leading edge cuff or droop to the outboard end of the wing which does the same thing.
